# Understanding the Android Visualizer class

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development (though I know a decent amount of java) and I'm trying to make a very simple plugin that can pass some variables to tasker. The end goal is that I want to use them for a sort of [bar visualizer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XbF-MqvZgs) for music in klwp. I want to use the [Visualizer class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) for this, but I am having trouble making heads or tails of how to use it by looking at the official documentation and various questions on here and some example code.

Say the bar visualizer, like in the link above, has 64 bars. Essentially all I want to do is get an array of 64 integers with a relative value of say 1-100 based on the FFT data? of the playing audio and then update them a few times a second. So for example, cut the frequency band into 64 "slices" and then take the average intensity of each one to get essentially the height of the corresponding bar on the visualizer. I don't even need to draw them in java, I just need the integers.

I don't know if I am going about it all wrong but I am having serious trouble figuring out how to implement that using Visualizer, I was wondering if someone could give me an example of how to implement it or explain how I would go about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these third party library for audio visualization:

1)https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4892   ( SIRIWaveView)

2)https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4622   (Audiogarm)

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for, those are just animations, it doesn't look like they actually display audio data. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: You can do it in audiogram and many other library are also there. It wil analyse the audio data and then set the wave accordingly.